# Like/unlike button in form

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there a way to put a like/unlike button in a list form rather than in the list itself? I tried to mimic the built-in button in the list itself, but it doesn't show the function or what it does.

What I'm trying to do is send a list item link to users and have them like it from within the form rather than going back to the list and search for the item and then like it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Go to the lists Settings. Choose Rating Settings. Select Yes in the field "Allow items in this list to be rated?" and select "Likes" in the field "Which voting/rating experience you would like to enable for this list?".
That should do it for you. 
Regards, Magnus

Comment: He asked besides the list, as far as I understood